# Need Regular Expression for path and file extension matching

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for C# to return a match for allowed paths and file names.

The following should match:

- `a` (at least one character)
- `xxx/bbb.aspx` (path allowed and only .aspx extension is allowed)
- `bbb.aspx?aaa=1` (querystring is allowed)

It should not match for:

- `aaa.`
- `aaa.gif` (only .aspx extension allowed)
- `aaa.anythingelse`

Comment: @alex: No. It has its own syntax (but is very similar and quite powerful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[\w/]+(\.aspx(\?.+)?)?
```

Comment: Had to change it slightly to accept names with hyphens: [-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(\.aspx(\?.+)?)?

Answer (score 0):

.NET has built-in features for working with file paths, including finding file extensions. So I would strongly suggest using them instead of a regex. Here is a possible solution using [System.IO.Path.GetExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx). This is untested but it should work.

```
private static bool IsValid(string strFilePath)
{
    //to deal with query strings such as bbb.aspx?aaa=1
    if(strFilePath.Contains('?'))
        strFilePath = strFilePath.Substring(0, strFilePath.IndexOf('?'));

    //the list of valid extensions
    string[] astrValidExtensions = { ".aspx", ".asp" };

    //returns true if the extension of the file path is found in the 
    //list of valid extensions
    return astrValidExtensions.Contains(
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strFilePath));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it for the URL rewriting system already in place so can't use this sorry.